# datetime index in python dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I am writing a program to download data from a website called quandl. The issue I am having is that when the data is downloaded the index column of the dataframe that it is downloaded, is dates in the format: 2000-01-02 00:00:00. When I then use `dates = df.index.values.tolist()` the dates are given back as integers in the form 946684800000000000 ( this being the date from before). Does anyone know how to handle this date format and put it into a format which I can use the datetime module with???

Comment: The dtype is `datetime64[ns]` probably, can you explain what you mean by `use the datetime with` you can convert to python datetime `df.index.to_pydatetime()`

Comment: Thanks for your help but answer is below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `df.index` is a `DatetimeIndex`, then use `df.index.to_pydatetime()` to convert the dates to an object array of `datetime.datetime`s.
For example,

```
In [14]: index = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=3, freq='D')

In [15]: index
Out[15]: DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-01', '2000-01-02', '2000-01-03'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D', tz=None)

In [16]: index.values.tolist()
Out[16]: [946684800000000000L, 946771200000000000L, 946857600000000000L]

In [17]: index.to_pydatetime()
Out[20]: 
array([datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 2, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 3, 0, 0)], dtype=object)
```

Note that depending on what you want to do with these dates, it may be more advantageous to work with a `DatetimeIndex` than an object array of `datetime.datetime`s.

---

**Tip**: This is the type of problem -- introspection of an unfamiliar object -- where [IPython](http://ipython.org/) can be of great help. IPython has TAB-completion of attributes. At the IPython prompt typing

```
In [17]: index.
```

and then pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> pulls up a list of all the attributes and methods of the `index` object that IPython has detected. (Because some objects have custom `__getattr__` methods, this may not be a complete list, but it is often useful nevertheless.) Perusing the list or doing a text search for "datetime" will lead you to `index.to_datetime` and `index.to_pydatetime`. A little experimentation will then show you that `index.to_pydatetime` does what you need. Moreover, typing a question mark after `index.to_pydatetime` causes IPython to show you helpful information, including the docstring:

```
In [19]: index.to_pydatetime?
Type:        instancemethod
String form: <bound method DatetimeIndex.to_pydatetime of DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-01', '2000-01-02', '2000-01-03'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D', tz=None)>
File:        /home/unutbu/.virtualenvs/dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.16.2+175.g5a9a9da-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/tseries/index.py
Definition:  index.to_pydatetime()
Docstring:
Return DatetimeIndex as object ndarray of datetime.datetime objects

Returns
-------
datetimes : ndarray
```